# В чем разница в объектах?

Tags: javascript

```js
// Запускаю все работает 

var a = {};
a.user = 'root';
a[name]  = 'hello';
alert(a[name]);

// Запускаю не работает ?!

var b = {};
b.name = 'roo';
b.num  = 12;
b[user] = 'fxz';
alert(b[user]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разница в том, что у глобального объекта `window` есть свойство `name`. А переменная `user` в `b[user]` действительно не объявлена.

```js
// Запускаю все работает 

var a = {};
a.user = 'root';
a[name]  = 'hello';
console.log(a);
```

```js
// Запускаю не работает ?!

var b = {};
b.name = 'roo';
b.num  = 12;
b[user] = 'fxz';
//alert(b[user]);
```

```js
// Запускаю - работает!

var b = {};
b.name = 'roo';
b.num  = 12;
b["user"] = 'fxz';
console.log(b);
```

Comment: почему во 2 объекте ошибка, если он как первый написан ?

Comment: @xes Написал объяснение в начале ответа.

Comment: я же по идеи могу обращаться к объекту через точку и через [] так почему ?

Comment: @xes Постарайтесь уловить разницу между вторым и третьим фрагментами кода.

Comment: a.user = "root"; идентична a[root]

Comment: @xes нет, не идентична

Comment: разница в кавычках

Comment: @xes `a.user = "root";` - то же самое, что `а["user"] = "root";`

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/object Доступ через квадратные скобки там же написано что js автоматом кавычки поставит или я неправильно понял ?

Comment: @xes да, Вы неправильно поняли

Comment: походу когда я доберусь 2 части мы будем часто случаться :)))

Comment: @xes обратите внимание, что везде, где они используют `obj[key]`, переменная `key` предварительно определена

Comment: потому что названию свойства объекта если мы его отправили в другую переменную единственный способ добраться это через []